# overloaded method value apply with alternatives

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
case class A[T](a:T, b:Array[Int])
object A {
  def apply[T](aa:T):A[T] = A(aa, Array(1, 2, 3))
}

trait TLike[T]
case class TSample1[T](str:String) extends TLike[T]
```

Why if I instantiate from `A` with type I get the following error:

```
object tmp extends App{
  val a = A[TLike[TSample1]](TSample1("dumb"))
}
```

Error:

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (a: TLike[TSample1],b: Array[Int])A[TLike[TSample1]] <and>
  (aa: TLike[TSample1])A[TLike[TSample1]]
 cannot be applied to (TSample1[Nothing])
  val a = A[TLike[TSample1]](TSample1("dumb"))
```

But if I just leave it to Scalac it works correctly:

```
object tmp extends App{
      val a = A(TSample1("dumb"))
    }
```

Comment: What is your intended purpose for the type parameter `T` in `TLike` and `TSample`? For instance, how does a `TSample[Int]` differ from a `TSample[Char]`? They would both take a `String` parameter, as written, but neither are of type `TSample[String]` or `TLike[String]`, and neither hold a `Int` or `Char` instance. I wonder if this factor may be confusing your usage in `tmp`.

Comment: @Shadowlands I've simplified my code to this, so I can ask the question, I need the T in trait for some other part of my code.

Answer (score 1):

If we start with your case that compiles, you call `object A`'s `apply` method, which works as expected.

If we later go to the example that doesn't compile and look at the compile error:

```
Main.scala:10: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
(a: TLike[TSample1],b: Array[Int])A[TLike[TSample1]] <and>
(aa: TLike[TSample1])A[TLike[TSample1]]
cannot be applied to (TSample1[Nothing])
val a = A[TLike[TSample1]](TSample1("dumb"))
       ^
one error found
```

It says that it finds two `apply` methods, one which you defined and one which is the standard `case class` method (read more about that if you need to).

I'm guessing you try to call this method:

`def apply[T](aa:T):A[T] = A(aa, Array(1, 2, 3))`

However you can't call the `A` object's apply function with a template. The other call doesn't match since it also needs an array. Also the types `TLike[TSample1]` is not equal to `TSample1`.

Comment: It shouldn't be confused about the apply method args, because one (case class) has two argument params and the other (object) has one argument

Comment: An `object` is instantiated once, therefore you cannot call it with template arguments as you do. Also the types are wrong. Please read my last sentence in my answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve here, but you should consider two things:

1. `TSample` take arguments, so `Tlike[TSample]` is pretty complex type
2. as there no hints in parameters in for `TSample.apply` what type parameter `T` should be, it would be inferred to `Nothing` by default

This for example would compile

```
A[TLike[TSample1[_]]](TSample1[TSample1[_]]("dumb"))
```

Whis would also:

```
A[TLike[Nothing]](TSample1("dumb"))
```

Latter is equivalent for

```
A(TSample1("dumb"))
```

without any type specification